# How to set naming strategy to ObjectMapper on Jackson 2.7+?

Tags: java, jackson

This code used to work with Jackson 2.6.x, but is not working with 2.7+.

```
// Lombok for code simplicity
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public static class Naming {
    int camelCase;
}

...
Naming naming = new Naming(1);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(
  PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);

System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(naming));
// "{\"camel_case\":1}" Jackson 2.6.x
// "{\"camelCase\":1}" Jackson 2.7.x
```

What've I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that the Lombok annotation `@AllArgsConstructor` caused the problem.

There's [a related issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1122) reported on GitHub. It seems like a bug of Jackson. It's reproducible with the version 2.7.0 and 2.7.1.